# Returning an n-dimensional data structure?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the following family of C# functions:

```
// 1D version
public Dictionary<int, double> GetNumCases1D(string varID1)
{
  Dictionary<int, double> cases1D = new Dictionary<int, double>();
  foreach (int value1 in ValuesFromVariable(varID1))
  {
    // do work
  }
  return cases1D;
}
// 2D version
public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>> GetNumCases2D(string varID1, string varID2)
{
  Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>> cases2D = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>>();
  foreach (int value2 in ValuesFromVariable(varID2))
  {
    // do work
    Dictionary<int, double> cases1D = new Dictionary<int, double>();
    foreach (int value in ValuesFromVariable(varID1))
    {
      // do more work
    }
  }
  return cases2D;
}
// 3D version
public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>>> GetNumCases3D(string varID1, string varID2, string varID3)
{
  Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>>> cases3D = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>>>();
  foreach (int value3 in ValuesFromVariable(varID3))
  {
    // do work
    Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>> cases2D = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>>();
    foreach (int value2 in ValuesFromVariable(varID2))
    {
      // do more work
      Dictionary<int, double> cases1D = new Dictionary<int, double>();
      foreach (int value in ValuesFromVariable(varID1))
      {
        // do more work^2
      }
    }
  }
  return cases3D;
}
```

What I would like is a single function version that could return an arbitrarily dimensioned data-structure, with a corresponding number of inner loops:

```
// n-dimensional version
public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, ... Dictionary<int, double>...>> GetNumCasesND(List<string> varIDs)
{
  Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, ... Dictionary<int, double>...>> casesND = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, ... Dictionary<int, double>...>>();
  foreach (int value1 in ValuesFromVariable(varIDs[0]))
  {
    // ??
    foreach (int value2 in ValuesFromVariable(varIDs[1]))
    {
      // ??
      ...
      foreach (int valueN in ValuesFromVariable(varIDs[N-1]))
      {
        // ??
      }
    }
  }
  return casesND;
}
```

This doesn't look like it's possible -- is it?  And is there a better way?

Comment: It is not a problem with your `GetNumCases()` code, it is a problem with the way you represent your data. A `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>>>` is a terribly bad way to represent data and should be punished with jail. You need to sit down and think what's the data that you're dealing with and create a proper set of `strongly typed` classes that represent that data, instead of using Dictionaries and `int`s for everything.

Comment: Many method parameters is making your program unmaintainable. An arbitrary number of *generic type parameters of a generic type with more generic type parameters of a generic type* will make your program completely impossible to both write, debug, maintain and pick up on later.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys.  I have an n-dimensional data (hyper)cube: as in, a structure equivalent to double values[i_1, i_2, ..., i_n] with n indices, where n is set at run-time.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don´t listen to the naysayers ;) Yes, it is possible, with a *little* adjustment. It was an interesting question, so I wanted to be sure myself.

This is the single method you asked for:

```
    public Dictionary<int, object> GetNumCasesNDim(params string[] input)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<int, object>();
        int dimensions = input.Length;

        if (dimensions == 1)
        {
            foreach (int value in ValuesFromVariable(input[dimensions - 1]))
            {
                result.Add(value, 0.01d /*dummy double*/);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (int value in ValuesFromVariable(input[dimensions - 1]))
            {
                var nextParams = new List<string>(input);
                nextParams.RemoveAt(nextParams.Count - 1);
                result.Add(value, GetNumCasesNDim(nextParams.ToArray()));                    
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Test code, to compare with your own 3D method. I took the liberty to fill out the blanks with dummy data.

```
    // 3D version
    public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>>> GetNumCases3D(string varID1, string varID2, string varID3)
    {
        var cases3D = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>>>();
        foreach (int value3 in ValuesFromVariable(varID3))
        {
            var cases2D = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>>();
            cases3D[value3] = cases2D;
            foreach (int value2 in ValuesFromVariable(varID2))
            {
                var cases1D = new Dictionary<int, double>();
                cases2D[value2] = cases1D;
                foreach (int value in ValuesFromVariable(varID1))
                {
                    cases1D.Add(value, value + 0.1d);
                }
            }
        }
        return cases3D;
    }

    private static int nIndex;
    private List<int> ValuesFromVariable(string s)
    {
        var result = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
            result.Add(++nIndex);
        return result;
    }

    // n-dimensional version
    public Dictionary<int, object> GetNumCasesNDim(params string[] input)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<int, object>();
        int dimensions = input.Length;

        if (dimensions == 1)
        {
            foreach (int value in ValuesFromVariable(input[dimensions - 1]))
            {
                result.Add(value, 0.01d);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (int value in ValuesFromVariable(input[dimensions - 1]))
            {
                var nextParams = new List<string>(input);
                int index = nextParams.Count - 1;
                nextParams.RemoveAt(index);
                result.Add(value, GetNumCasesNDim(nextParams.ToArray()));                    
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void test()
    {
        nIndex = 0;
        var dim3 = GetNumCases3D("this", "is", "a");

        nIndex = 0;
        var testDimN = GetNumCasesNDim("this", "is", "a");

        nIndex = 0;
        var test2DimN = GetNumCasesNDim("this", "is", "a", "test");            
    }
```

Comment: Much appreciated, Jon -- thank you!  I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

It's just not possible because your return type has to be known at compile time, but the pseudo code you've written depends on the number of elements in `varIDs` which isn't known until run time.

Comment: Thanks John -- I thought there might be a generic or templated type that could deal with this in some way.  So what do people normally do in this situation (where they want an n-dimensional structure returned)?

Comment: @EdGraham: What they normally do in this situation is re-think their data model. You need to ask yourself what you're really trying to achieve, and if there's some other organization of the data that would be more intuitive and easier to code.

Comment: Thanks Jim.  I have an n-dimensional data (hyper)cube: as in, a structure equivalent to  double values[i_1, i_2, ..., i_n]  where n is set at run-time.  Any ideas for re-thinking?

Comment: It is possible, if the return type is Dictionary<int, object>. Take a look at my code. Not very pretty, but it works.

Comment: True, it's possible if you are willing to give up type safety... As asked it looked more like he wanted to keep it strongly typed. @EdGraham There is a way to write templates that turn into c# code using T4 templates, which you could use to generate a finite number of dimensions. See more at http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
class MultidimensionalArray<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, TValue> _impl = new Dictionary<string, TValue>();

    public TValue this[IEnumerable<TKey> index]
    {    
        get { return _impl[ToStringKey(index)]; }
        set { _impl[ToStringKey(index)] = value; }
    }

    public TValue this[params TKey[] index]
    {
        get { return this[index.AsEnumerable()]; }
        set { this[index.AsEnumerable()] = value; }
    }

    private string ToStringKey(IEnumerable<TKey> key)
    {
        return string.Join(";", key.Select(k => k.ToString()));
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var arr = new MultidimensionalArray<int, double>();
arr[1, 2, 3] = 3.5;
Console.WriteLine(arr[1, 2, 3]);
```

**Easy extension:**

```
class MultidimensionalArray<TValue>: MultidimensionalArray<object, TValue> {}
```

**Usage:**

```
var arr = new MultidimensionalArray<double>();
arr['Y', "Hell", 0] = 3.5;
Console.WriteLine(arr['Y', "Hell", 0]);
```

Another approach would be to use `dynamic`.

Comment: Thanks very much, Grozz -- I'll look into it tomorrow.